# Set TCP Client received data (External Thread) to TextView (Main Thread)

Tags: java, android, multithreading, performance

I have created an Android App that handles a TCP Client connection with an AsyncTask. Server-Client interaction works perfectly. Now, I have a question about the implementation I have made to pass a String from the Client Thread to the Main Thread:

I want to set the received String from the Client Thread to a TextView, and non-main threads cannot interact with the App UI on Android.

So what I did was to create a temporary thread on the Main one that checks every 100ms if the data has been received on the Client thread, and then use it.

Here are the simplified pieces of code:

**Client Thread (No access to UI)**

```
private volatile boolean hasReceivedData;
private String receivedData;

 ...

receivedData = inBuffer.readLine();
hasReceivedData = true;

 ...

public String getReceivedData() {
    return receivedData;
}
```

**Main App Thread (Access to UI)**

```
private ClientThread client;
private TextView textView;
private Thread dataChecker;

 ...

dataChecker = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (!client.hasReceivedData()) {
                Utils.sleep(100);
            }
            textView.setText(client.getReceivedData());
        }
});
dataChecker.start();
```

I would like to know if there is a better/correct way to achieve this or a simpler one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` has `onPostExecute()` method, which runs after `doInBackground()` thread is completed. Use that to update the UI.